# Gridview with add button

Tags: android, xml, gridview, android-gridview

I'm going to create gridview with a button as last item of gridview which i want to use it as add button .

For example:
When you click the button (item 1) add to gridview and (add button) go to Second item

---

Item1 Button

Item1 Item2
Item3 Item4
Button

---

Something like top style

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://chintanrathod.com/recyclerview-android-studio-part-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you got what i did to achieve this.
MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
GridAdapter adapter;
List<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list.add("Test " + i);
    }
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    adapter = new GridAdapter(this, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.stackoverflow.MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now make an adapter for gridView

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<String> list;
Context context;

public GridAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    textView.setText(list.get(position));
    if (list.size() - 1 == position) {
        linearLayout.addView(addButton());
    }
    return view;
}

private Button addButton() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setText("Testing");
    return button;
}

}
```

And gridItem.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It is the main idea that you get the last item and add a button at last. You can refine this code and also could use recyclerView. Now when you add an item to list then call notifyDataSetChanged();
Hope it will help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is that, You can design multiple grid-item layouts as per your requirements. And then in "getView" method of Adapter class you can check which xml to inflate as a view.

hope this will help you to dig it up.